# an strange set $ \Xi_A =$ {$ n \in N | \exists k^2 \in A $ s.t $ k^2 \leq n$} is decidable ?, an Interview questions?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

We are some student that had an Interview for M.sc Entrance Exam. This interview has two part and one multiple choice question. We see 1 strange question that some definition is so strange for us, we decide to ask it here:

> $$ \Xi_A = \{ n \in N \mid \exists k^2 \in A : k^2 \leq n \}, \quad A \text{ is an arbitrary r.e set.}$$

The multiple choice is as follows:

I) $ \Xi_A$ is decidable.

II) $ \Xi_A$ is r.e but is not decidable.

III) $ \Xi_A$ is not an r.e set, but complement of $ \Xi_A$ is r.e set.

IV) $ \Xi_A$ just only is r.e when $A$ be r.e-complete.

The questioner say which is choice is correct? infact we never see this type of question. powerful person that is on MSE site, would you please help us in negotiating with this question?

Edit 1: some of student says I is correct, but just guess after interview :)

Comment: Are you sure $\exists k^2$ shouldn't just be $\exists k$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, make it me strange...

Comment: Is $A$ meant to be an arbitrary set?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, it's added, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the definition is really
$$ \Xi_A = \{ n \in N \mid \exists k \in A: k^2 \leq n \} $$
(because $\exists k^2\in A$ is not syntactically well-formed), then the answer is (I): $\Xi_A$ is decidable no matter what $A$ is.

This is a well-known family of "trick questions", where the underlying point is that whether a set is decidable (or not) or r.e. (or not) depends **only** on what its elements are -- *not* on how the set is defined.

In this case there are two possibilities:

**Either** $A$ is empty. In that case $\Xi_A$ is empty too, and the empty set is trivially decidable.

**Or** $A$ contains a smallest element $k_0$.  In that case $\Xi_A$ is the same set as $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\ge k_0^2\}$. This is trivially decidable too -- you just build the number $k_0^2$ into the deciding program as a literal constant and compare to it.

If the definition of $A$ is complicated (or it's just a random set that doesn't *have* a definition), we may not *know* which of these two cases hold -- or what $k_0$ is in the second case. But we *can* know that some program that happens to decide exactly the set $\Xi_A$ *exists*, even if we can't know which program that is.

Note that we don't need to assume that $A$ is r.e. for this argument to work -- it is true for *every* $A\subseteq \mathbb N$, even ones that are not r.e. or not arithmetical.

Comment: there is a typo.... in your answer..

Comment: @nini: That information would be more useful if you described what it is (or edit the answer to fix it if you're _sure_ it's a typo).

Comment: We have 1 questions, if $ \exists k^2$ is true, again the argument is true?

Comment: @nini: Probably yes -- but $\exists k^2$ is not standard notation, so _in principle_ it could mean something weird, depending on which meaning the author of the problem decides to give it. Most reasonable guesses at at its possible meaning would not make any difference here, though.